# Querying pages in WordPress by template name

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a template named "Foo" in "foo.php", I would like to be able to select all pages that are using that template. I have searched for awhile now but have not been able to find a successful way to do this... Can somebody enlighten me on the proper/only way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this by using following code

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'foo.php' ) );

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: If you add `'post_type' => 'page'` this will work. Thank you!

Comment: and also just in case 'hierarchical' => 0

Comment: To clarify on this (and Jessie Baltazar's solution), if your template is kept in a subdirectory, you'll have to include that in the meta_value.  For example, `'meta_value' => 'templates/template-contact.php'`

Comment: Shouldn't `if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` be `if ( $query->have_posts() ) while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();`?

Answer (score 8):

Robot's answer is good, but I thought I'd clarify a few things.

First, You should use the variable for the query you created, so it would be $query->have_posts() etc.

Second, you should specify post_type. I used any, so that it will pull any post types except for revisions.

Last, if this is in a page with any other WP loops, you may want to use wp_reset_query. I added one below and one above just in case, but you only really need this if you have another loop above or below. Remove it if you don't.

Here is the code:

```
wp_reset_query();
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'any',
    'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'foo.php'
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); // WP loop
        the_title();
    endwhile; // end of the loop.
} else { // in case there are no pages with this template
    echo 'No Pages with this template';
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Hope that helps someone!! Happy coding!

Comment: THANNK YOU!!!!  This was the only way I could get the query to recognize my template after creating a page and making it a child.  It must have been the 'post_type' => 'any'?

Answer (score 5):

This also works

```
$pages = get_pages(

     array(

    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',

    'meta_value' => 'template.php'
       )
);

foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->post_title.'<br />';
}
```

http://jorgepedret.com/old/web-development/get-pages-by-template-name-in-wordpress/

Comment: How do I add pagination also?

Comment: Not up to date. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29918/page-template-query-with-wp-query